# odoo11, Multiple Journal in one entry

Tags: move, account, odoo-11

I develop a new custom module to implement batch payment (Many transaction in one time)

Now I can dot it for Send/Receive Money perfectly

**

My Problem

** on transfer money between journal (Bank & Cash).
it does not accept to implement more than one journal.id in same entry and also convert the destination_account_id to transfer_account

any ideas ??

Update,

Inheriting the Method "_compute_destination_account_id" Solve the problem of destination account

Remaining to add multiple journal

Answer (score 0):

Update,

I solve that problem by updating directly to database --> passing Odoo restrictions